# Access a hidden file programatically in Windows RT?

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1, windows-rt

Is there any way to access hidden files programatically in Windows RT?

Whenever I try to do GetFileAsync for a hidden file, I get UnauthorizedAccessException.

Answer (score 2):

Not from the Windows Runtime API.

If the file is in your app data folder you can use the Win32 file API to find and manipulate the hidden file, but your app won't have permissions to do that elsewhere in the file system.